# undefined local variable or method `user' in Users#index [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out why the @user variable is not being found.  It's throwing the error inside of a view where I try to link to the user, and it mentions the index of Users.
What am I doing wrong?

More info:  They login via a session page, and then I redirect them to the "User view" to then use the application as a logged in user.  The session is created successfully.

Routes.rb

```
resources :users
resources :sessions
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create!(user_params)
    redirect_to users_path, notice: "Successfully created #{@user.name}"
  end

  def index
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit!
  end
end
```

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "Logged in as #{@user.name}"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
  end

end
```

User View

```
<%= link_to user.name, edit_user_path(user) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` variable in your view is being seen as a local variable, which is undefined.  Use `@user` instance variable instead of `user` as it's `@user` that's defined in your `index` action.

```
<%= link_to @user.name, edit_user_path(@user) %>
```

**Update:**

So basically the problem was in the OP's `user`'s migration, the option `id: false` was set.  Which led to creation of `users` table without the `id` column and `@user.id` was always nil.  Removing this option from the migration fixed the issue!

Comment: When I do this it gives me an error of [undefined method `name'] and the "name" does exist as a string in my Users table.

Comment: Can you post the URL you're using get to the `index` action.  You're expecting `email` parameter, do you have that parameter in the URL?

Comment: No, I don't.  When the session is created, it redirects to the user page.  I figured a user would be able to know who is logged in.  What happens is in the "create" function of the sessions controller above when someone logs in.  So how can I reference the "user" who is currently logged in?

Comment: Since you're setting `session[:user_id]` in your `SessionsController#create`, you could use `User.find(session[:user_id])` to get the currently logged in user.

Comment: Well this brings to yet another error, LOL.  I don't understand what is asking.  The error is [Couldn't find User without an ID] in UsersController#index.  Why would it not be able to find a user without an ID when the ID is created automatically when I save my new user in the Users Controller?  Also, I just passed it an ID to find by what you mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: The problem might be in your `create` action.  If you're visiting `index` directly then you'll certainly get that error.  If you are going through `create` then you then need to ensure the presence of `params[:email]` as well.  And by the way, shouldn't you be using `user_params` and not `params`?

Comment: I don't know the difference between user_params and params except in your comment I assume that user_params is all parameters associated with a user.  Is that correct?  Also, I don't understand "If you are going through create then you then need to ensure the presence of params[:email] as well."

Comment: Also, when I changed "params" to "user_params" in the sessions controller it gives an error of undefined.  It doesn't recognize "user_params"

Comment: Apologies if I have confused you.  I suggest you to look at [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem which takes care of the authentication and related session management.  I'm up for a chat to discuss on the previous comments as writing here would make it less readable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49830/discussion-between-camdixon-and-vee)